# Is there a way to create "Undocumented" entry in doxygen output html?

Tags: doxygen

I wanted to list all classes/functions that don't have documentation using doxygen but it seems like it doesn't generate specific entry for that by default. I also wanted to post it to my server, so in-terminal warnings are not good to go

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Did you have a look at the `WARN_LOGFILE` setting and other `WARN...` settings? Did you have a look at the setting of `EXTRACT_ALL` and other `EXTRACT_...` settings. Note `EXTRACT_ALL` suppresses most warnings though.

Comment: @albert doxygen 1.9.1. Yes, I enabled `EXTRACT_ALL` option. I didn't look at warn logfiles and thought that there should be a way to make it using doxygen functionality. Otherwise, i will have to think how to upload that warn file to the server in an automated way and how to properly show it in the page, etc, etc..

Comment: There is no direct way see the file directly, so you have to upload it yourself and also there is no direct way to include the file in the (HTML) output (a bit of a chicken egg problem).